# Upload file to directory on server using Java and JSP - can't get path right

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

On my vps, I want to upload a file to the Logos directory. 
The directory structure is as follows on my vps -
/home/webadmin/domain.com/html/Logos

When a file is uploaded through my jsp page, that file is renamed, and then I want to put it into the Logos directory.... but I can't seem to get the path right in my servlet code.

Snippet of servlet code -

```
String upload_directory="/Logos/"; // path to the upload folder

File savedFile = new File(upload_directory,BusinessName+"_Logo."+fileExtension);

//.....
//file saved to directory
//.....
```

I've tried many variations, but still fail. What is the proper way to specify the path?

**Edited**
The problem with using getServletContext() is that it returns the path to the directory where Tomcat and my webapp is...whereas I want to reach the directory where my html and image files are - under the root directory of the vps. How do I specify that path?

```
    String server_path = getServletContext().getRealPath("/"); // get server path.                      

    //server_path = /opt/tomcat6/webapps/domain.com/

    String upload_directory = "Logos/"; // get path to the upload folder.

    String complete_path = server_path + upload_directory; // get the complete path to the upload folder.

    //complete_path = /opt/tomcat6/webapps/domain.com/Logos/

    File savedFile = new File(complete_path,"NewLogo.jpg");

    //savedFile = /opt/tomcat6/webapps/domain.com/Logos/NewLogo.jpg
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a common practice to make the path for storage configurable - either via some `application.properties` file, or if you don't have such a properties file - as a `context-param` in `web.xml`. There you configure the path to be the absolute path, like:

```
configuredUploadDir=/home/webadmin/domain.com/html/Logos
```

Obtain that value in your code (depending on how you stored it), and have:

```
File uploadDir = new File(configuredUploadDir);
```

**Note**: make sure you have the permissions to read and write the target directory.

Comment: I put the <context-param> in the main web.xml file and specified the folder path. Then called the param in the servlet like so -- (FileUploadPath = getServletContext().getInitParameter("FileUploadPath"); -- and unfortunately, its still not putting the pic in that folder location. I don't understand why...

Comment: @katura - debug (or print to console) the value of the parameter.

Comment: @Bozho - Value of parameter prints out - /home/webadmin/domain.com/html/Logos

Comment: @katura - ok. So, any exception? can you check that you have write permissions? Does the directory exist? (`file.exists()` returns what?)

Comment: No exceptions. Checked Tomcat log, everything good. Directory exists, I created it on the server. In fact, there was a keyword in your last comment that held the answer to this problem...and boy do I feel stupid now... 'permissions' - I needed to set Write permission on the folder to permit writing from the 'Owner', 'Group' and 'Other'. Thank you for helping me solve this problem. I additionally liked the suggestion of putting the folder path in as a <context-param> in the web.xml file. Many thanks to you! Should I mark your answer as correct since the comments contain the answer?

Comment: @katura - yes, feel free to mark it as accepted. I will add the permission thing into the answer as well

Answer (score 2):

You can use following code in any jsp or servlet.

> 1) String serverPath= getServletContext().getRealPath("/");

This will give you full path of the server from root directory to your web application directory.
For me its: **"D:\local\tomcat-6.0.29\webapps\myapp"** when I sysout from myapp application.

Once you got the whole real path for the server system as above you can get the path relative to your directory. So if I have some data file in **myapp\data** - I can get it appending **\data\filename** to the serverPath which we got earlier.
This will work in all situation even you have multiple servers installed on the same system.

2) You can get server home from **system properties** using

> System.getProperty("TOMCAT_HOME")

and then can use this **absolute path** in your program

3) To pass absolute directory path to any servlet using `<init-param>`

Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the problem is: the File constructor doesn't create the file, only prepares to for the creation, then, after you construct a file instance you must invoke the method createNewFile(), and thats all.

Answer (score 0):

The path "/Logos/" will attempt to create the file in the root of your system, which is not what you want. Look at the ServletContext.getRealPath() method.

Comment: I've appended additional information to my original post regarding using ServletContext.getRealPath - that isn't giving me what I want.

Comment: So your HTML and image files aren't in the same directory as you JSP files? That would be the normal spot for them. But in your case just setting upload_directory to "html/Logos/" should do the trick.

Comment: That is correct, Html and Image files are not in the same directory as the Jsp pages. I will try your suggestion and if it doesn't work, I guess I'll just have to put the image files in with the jsp pages.